# How to access file from staticfiles_dirs within django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, static-files

In my settings.py I have set the staticfiles_dirs as so

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'static')).replace('\\','/') 
)
```

and in the folder myproject/static I have a file called jquery-1.10.0.js. I have tried to load the file in my app's template like this

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "jquery-1.10.0.js" %}"></script>
```

but I cannot access the jquery functions from within my template and if I go to the url that `{% static "jquery-1.10.0.js" %}` returns, which is /static/jquery-1.10.0.js, I get a page that says A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

How do I access the jquery file from within the template?

Comment: Which version of Django? Is debug mode on? Any error on the console?

Comment: can you not just do `/static/jquery-1.10.0.js`?

Comment: Check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554845/loading-images-in-a-static-file/16554949#16554949 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389989/static-files-are-not-loaded-in-django/16390679#16390679 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615224/i-cant-define-staticfiles-dirs-using-python-to-figure-out-the-path/16615325#16615325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of silly but the reason I couldn't access the static file was because I didn't add a comma to the end of the first element in the staticfiles_dirs tuple.

The reason it didn't work in the first place was because a comma was needed at the end in order for python to recognize the staticfiles_dirs variable as a tuple.